# How to display only the modal image and hide the main design

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below are the style and scripts of my modal pop up.The same style and scripts are used in all the pages but in one particular page it show the image in this way [how to hide the blue coloured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kQPZ.png)  and display only the pop up image.I need to hide the div wrapper on clicking the image.How can i  do this

```
 <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="z-index:1001">
  <span class="close">×</span>
 <%-- <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="images/MeetingQA.PNG">--%>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img02" src="images/Meeting1.PNG" />
    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
        //var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var modalImg1 = document.getElementById("img02");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".categories").hide();
            $(".content").hide();
            //modalImg.src = "HelpDocs/MeetingQA.PNG";
            modalImg1.src = "HelpDocs/AR/Reports/Collection%20Completed%20Work/Collectioncompleted_Agent.PNG";
        }
        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

  <style>
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
      -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I get this when I try to run the code snippet: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 111,
  "colno": 25
} Try using other online editor so that it would be easier to solve the problem

Comment: I guess you need something like this http://www.cssscript.com/demo/easy-image-lightbox-slider-integration-lightbox-js/

Comment: you tried the link?